# BeautifulSoup parsing returns None

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

There are plenty of websites thats simply return `None` when I request a value from the website.

Example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def spider():
    url = 'https://poloniex.com/exchange'
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
    High = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "high info"})[0].string
    print High
    # returns None    

spider()
```

How do i solve this problem? Please, all I need is a value.

Comment: There is no text, it is dynamically generated  so what else would you expect?

Comment: there is no text, look into the source code <div class="high info"></div>

Comment: so how do i grabe the dynamically generated text?

Comment: @solidsnake, use something like selenium that can run js

Answer (score 0):

The web page has JavaScript code, and because of this the request doesn't return a complete result (the JS code in this case is necessary to complete the page).

I'm using selenium to solve this kind of problem.

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Download chromedriver from this link http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.24/ and uzip it &  Put chromedriver.exe in C:\Python27\Scripts

try this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url= "https://poloniex.com/exchange"
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(5)
content = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8').strip()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"html.parser")
High = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "high info"})[0].string
print High
driver.quit()
```

It will print:

```
0.02410000
```

Hope this helps